# How to refetch apollo watchQuery after cache invalidation with cache-first / cache-and-network

Tags: graphql, apollo-client, react-apollo, react-apollo-hooks

I have some meta data which rarely updates, but it can update once in a while. Within my application the user access this information very frequently, which puts quite some load on my servers.

I'd like to refetch it only eg once a day to check if something changed.

My expected behavior is watchQuery should immediately return, even though cache is expired. Only if cache is expired it refetches to update cache

Is this anyhow possible?

My first idea was to tell cache-and-network or cache-first to only use network if the last network check is eg older than an day or cache got invalidated, but could not find anything on this in the document.

Thx I really appreciate your expertise.